# Convex hull of halfspace and point is not a polyhedron

Tags: general-topology, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $S=conv(H \cup\{x\} )$ denote the convex hull of $H \cup\{x\}$ where $H \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ is a halfspace and $x\in\Bbb{R}^n, x\notin H$.

I need to prove that $S$ is not a polyhedron and my definition of a polyhedron is a finite intersection of halfspaces, ie $P$ is a halfspace if $P=\bigcap_{i=1}^{m}H_i$ for each $H_i$ a halfspace.

Is it sufficient to show that a single point is an infinite intersection of halfspaces or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: When you say "halfspace," do you assume it must be closed?

Comment: Yes, $H_i = \{x\in \Bbb{R}^n : \alpha^T x \le \beta\}$ for $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}^n$ and $\beta \in \Bbb{R}$ as the definition of a halfspace

Answer (score 5):

First, show that any element of $S$ can be written as a convex combination of $x$ with a single element of $H$.

Then, if you draw all rays from $x$ that intersect $H$, you will see that $S$ is basically the union of $\{x\}$ with an *open* half space whose boundary intersects $x$ and is parallel to that of $H$. Then $S$ is not closed (it contains points arbitrarily close to the boundary, but not the boundary), whereas polytopes must be closed by your definition.